# Best practices for modifying foundation CSS framework

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

In implementing foundation.css framework, shall I update the actual foundation.css for my custom needs (font colors, backgrounds, etc) or shall I use a secondary css for my customization so that when foundation.css needs updating I can replace it without losing my customization.

Let me know your thoughts on this strategy. This would be the code the second option above:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" media="screen, projection" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/my-custom.css" media="screen, projection" />
```

Thank you

Comment: This is not "not constructive". It's a good question and one that I have chatted with to various developers. The conclusion I found is this varies per project, the number of developers involved, and how often the framework itself will be updated.

Comment: There will be some differing of opinion here but this is a real question and deserves a real answer.  The accepted one is only partially correct and not comprehensive enough to explain the alternatives, which really vary by use-case more than by opinion.

Comment: The third, unmentioned, and often most-correct option is to make use of the precompiler source provided (sass in this case) which is used to build the framework's CSS.  These frameworks tend to make heavy use of variables to theme the base styles, which can be overridden *without modifying the source*, allowing for it to remain intact for future updates.  If your own goal is to essentially theme the framework (and not use it as a jumping off point for heavy modification), then this is very often the acceptable best practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I think this is more an opinion request than a real question.
Still, I'd say the answer is, as always in these cases, it depends.

You can certainly override the original stylings with a second css, and I think that's what they suggested on their docs (haven't been using Foundation during the last, I think, 6 months, sorry). It will just work ok, and your future upgrades will be easier to integrate, in case the framework will get some. This is certainly a perfect future-proof approach.

Performance-wise I'd suggest to directly customise that very css. My reasons are:

- **Less KB**: Your css will be lighter = faster to load.
- **Less DOM painting**: the browser won't have to style elements the Foundation way and then style them again your way.
- **Less HTTP requests**: the browser will only download one css, saving one extra HTTP request (fater load time)

So, it's really up to you, as you're the only one who knows if the website will need a framework update.
I never had the need of an update when I used Foundation, and I think it's been tested quite a lot that *vital* updates will hardly be needed.